# Double entry accounting: as an employee, how do I enter expenses in foreign currency?

Tags: gnucash, double-entry, expense-tracking

I use gnucash. For my company expenses I follow advices from [In double entry accounting, as an employee, how do I enter expenses?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/35453/in-double-entry-accounting-as-an-employee-how-do-i-enter-expenses) and I am happy with the results. 

But I get to travel often to country with different currency, and I do not know how to do the same thing with expenses generated when working abroad. 

Also, as I go often I have bank accounts in both currencies as well as many expenses accounts doubled because of the currencies.

I have created the following accounts:

```
Personal bank GBP: asset
Personal bank EUR: asset
Transport expense GBP: expense
Transport expense EUR: expense
Reimbursement due from employer GBP: asset
Salary GBP: income
Reimbursements GBP: income
```

Currently, whenever I pay a taxi I create a split like this:

```
Debit transport expense GBP $30
Credit personal bank GBP $30

Debit reimbursement due GBP $30
Credit reimbursement GBP $30
```

How do I expand this to reclaim travel expenses in EUR in a sigle split as I am doing now with expenses in GBP?

Answer (score 3):

I may answer myself.

I am afraid it was not my day when I tried it first. The split is exactly the same, but I have to take close attention at the exchange rate of the two eur<>gbp conversions (asset:"reimbursement due" and income:"Reimbursements")

```
Debit "transport expense EUR" 30€
Credit "personal bank EUR" 30€

Debit "reimbursement due GBP" 30€ (+exchange rate)
Credit "reimbursement GBP" 30€ (+exchange rate)
```